# Python: module to share post on facebook and twitter

Tags: python, django, facebook, twitter

I've build an Admin panel to post contents on front-end such as Articles.

This admin is created using Django Admin.

How can I share newly posted article on *Facebook* and *Twitter*?

Comment: Do you want to automatically share your new posts to facebook just after creation ? or...  Do you want to add a button to give the users the possibility of sharing in facebook ?

Comment: Yes, I want to automatically share just after creation. @Liarez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use post_save signal which allows you to hook on a new object creation, for example:

```
from django.db       import models
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Article(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

@receiver(post_save, sender = Article)
def new_article_event(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    # Put facebook/twitter post code here
```

It's important that you'll check if created is True, to make sure you perform posting only on new articles.

You can use the following projects to post on Facebook/Twitter:

Facebook: https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

Twitter: https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

Answer (score 0):

To share automatically after creation you have 2 options:

1. Signals
2. Overwrite Article - Save method

---

## Signals

You should create a file `signals.py` in the same path as *views.py*, *settings.py*, etc...

and then customize like this (Let's supose your ModelName is **Article**):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(article_save, sender=Article)
def create_article(sender, **kwargs):
    article = kwargs['instance']
    #  SHARE FACEBOOK CODE USING ARTICLE DATA
```

## Overwrite Article save method

```
class Article(models.Model):
    field=...
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # SHARE FACEBOOK CODE USING ARTICLE DATA.
        self.something  # self points to current article

        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

To know how to do the sharing part I recommend you to read here: [Facebook Sharer title and sumamry customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065179/facebook-sharer-title-and-summary-customization)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Liarez, 
But this is not the answer I'm asking for. I'm asking the SDK implementation on server side to share posts same like Wordpress and Tumblr does. They posts on my timeline and tweets too.