# Share facebook url in html using handlebar templates

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, handlebars.js

I am trying to share my content on Facebook. Right now I am trying to create url like so.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]={{encodeURL data.url}}&p[title]={{data.itemTitle}}
```

url and title needs to be dynamic and encodeURL is a helper that run encodeURIComponent function on string. **Right now, url loads up but title is not being shown.**

I think sharer no longer support params as mentioned in following post.

https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/

I have gone through og meta tags as mentioned in many threads.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="myurl"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="my title" />
```

But in handlebars, I have one default file that have head tag that runs at start of application. And also I need to have dynamic url and title.
Can any body provide me some hints or resources?

Comment: I ran into the same problem of adding dynamic url and title.
Adding these tags dynamically from client side (js/jquery) will not work because the Facebook Crawler will render your page details before your tags been added.
The only solution that worked for me was adding the `og meta` tags dynamically from server side on page init.

Comment: But title not being loaded even if I add static content like  http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=www.mysite.com&p[title]=mytitle

Comment: The parameterized title is no longer supported. Facebook crawler picks the title from the `title` tag or `meta` tag

Comment: This may help you. [Facebook Sharer Title and summary customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065179/facebook-sharer-title-and-summary-customization)