# How to properly set Facebook Sharing Link Thumbnail and Text

Tags: django

I am trying to add a Facebook Sharing Link to my blog post detail page. So It is currently working but I have a question which didn't find an accurate answer to:

How to set the thumbnail and text after I press the sharing button on the popup page?

Here is the HTML

```
<!-- Sharingbutton Facebook -->
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ request.build_absolute_uri }}">
Share on Facebook
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: I want to set a specific image and title? Currently it is just showing `127.0.0.1` twice under each other

Comment: @crimsonpython24 Sorry for that I added an Image to be more descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you must do more. From what I've found, you have two ways to look at this:

**1. Django-related**

There are plugins that can help you achieve this; since you didn't mention this in your question, I'll assume that you haven't tried both. Here are a few:

- [Django-social-share](https://github.com/fcurella/django-social-share)
- [Django-socialsharing](https://github.com/lettertwo/django-socialsharing)
- [Or more packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/social/)

**2. Javascript, javascript, and more javascript**

I haven't tried this one, but it might work since it's provided by Facebook itself. [FB documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) and [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24257496). Try this one only if the first one didn't work.